# Hibernate, change the updatedTimestamp of child records on changes in parent records

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-keys, hibernate-envers

I have a spring boot application with with Hibernate. I have the following tables.

```
@Entity
public class Application1 {

   @JoinColumn(name = "form_id")
   @OneToOne
   Form form;

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  Timestamp updateDateTime;

   <<other fields  here>> 
}

@Entity
public class Application2 {

   @JoinColumn(name = "form_id")
   @OneToOne
   Form form;

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  Timestamp updateDateTime;

   <<other fields  here>> 
}

@Entity
public class Form {

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  Timestamp updateDateTime;

   <<other fields  here>> 
}
```

the column **updateDateTime** is getting updated for every updates of corresponding tables. But what I want is to update the **updateDateTime** of **Application1** and **Applicatin2** tables whenever there is a change in **Form** table

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely need a bi-directional relationship here. Add appropriate dependency on the `Form` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Form {

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  Timestamp updateDateTime;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "form")
  private Application application;
```

Comment: Great. Glad i could help